# VueJS pass props to children in render function call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, render, vuejs2

I have a parent component that wraps multiple children 'child'. I want the parent to essentially have the same template as the vanilla markup which is why I am using the render function.

I want the parent to manage the state of which child is active. But the props don't appear to be passing down to the children.

I have tried applying what the **[documentation says](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth)**, but props are undefined on the children. However if I do `item.data.staticClass = 'testing-class';` that class applies to each child.

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement) {
    this.$options._renderChildren.forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (item.data === undefined) //whitespace?
      return; 
      
      item.data.props = {
        activeindex: this.activeIndex,
        index: index
      }
    }.bind(this));
    
    return createElement('div', {}, this.$options._renderChildren);
  }
});

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>Im a child</div>',
  props: ['activeindex', 'index'],
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$props); //undefined
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uxvqh7f7/2/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think that `this.$props` will always be undefined. The `$props` property is accessible in a template like `{{ $props }}`, but those inline properties (frustratingly) don't always map up directly to the `this` variable available in the component's script. You can see the component's prop values using `this.$options.propsData`.

Secondly, you can use `item.componentOptions.propsData` to set the property values of the child component. (I think `item.data.props` is a misnomer referencing something else). [Here's a fiddle with the change.](https://jsfiddle.net/uxvqh7f7/4/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to assist. I actually realised this but hadn't had time to post an answer as it has lead to more problems with parent/child communication! EG: https://jsfiddle.net/zqufydvc/1/